# more than one label in Graphics3D

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, labeling

I'm trying to add some information to my Graphics3D Plot. At the moment I output the value of a function that changes when I use the sliders. I do that with PlotLabel. I need more data to be displayed so I tried to have more PlotLabel functions devided by a comma. Doesn't work unfortunately. This is my Graph:

```
    Grid[{Manipulate[
   Graphics3D[
    Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}} , 
     rad[v,h]], Axes -> Automatic, PlotLabel->o[h]], {h, 0.1, 1, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {v, 0.1, 1, 
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}]
```

Also I would like to display some information to the number that is put out by the function o[h], but I was not able to do that.
Any help, hints, links are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are `rad[v, h]` and `o[h]`?

Comment: Maybe something like `PlotLabel -> Column[{o[h], oo[v], ooo[o+v], "and so on"}]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rad[v_, h_] := v + h; (* for example *)
```

Here are a few ways to add multiple labels in/around a graphics object:

```
Manipulate[Labeled[Graphics3D[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, h}}, rad[v, h]], 
  PlotLabel -> Column[Style[#, 20] & /@ {Row[{oo[h], ooo[v]}, ","], 
     ooo[v + h],  "... so on"}, Alignment -> Center],
  Axes -> Automatic], 
  {Style[oooo[v], "Subsection"], Rotate[Style[ooo[h], "Subsection"], -Pi/2]},
  {{Top, Left}, {Right, Top}}],
 {h, 0.1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {v, 0.1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

You can also use `"\n"`(newline) instead of `Column` in `PlotLabel` setting. For example:

```
PlotLabel -> (Style[#, 20] &[
   ToString[oo[h]] <> ", " <> ToString[ooo[v]] <> "\n" <> 
    ToString[ooo[v + h]] <> "\n... so on\nso forth"])
```

Alternatively, you can use `StringForm` as follows:

```
PlotLabel -> Style[#, 20] &[StringForm["``  ``\n``\n... so on\nand so forth", 
  oo[h], ooo[v], ooo[v + h]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @kguler. Just need some time now how your code works. But the result is exactly what I had in mind :)